# How do I use multiple SSL certificates on google_compute_target_https_proxy?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

When looking at the documentation for [`google_compute_target_https_proxy`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/r/compute_target_https_proxy.html)
it says that it supports one one SSL certificate:

> ssl_certificates - (Required) A list of SslCertificate resources that are used to authenticate connections between users and the load balancer. Currently, exactly one SSL certificate must be specified.

But looking at the [Google Cloud documentation](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/ssl-certificates#multiple-example) there is an example with multiple SSL certificates.

Why is this blocked in the Terraform GCP provider and how can I make this work without editing it manually?

Comment: Have you tried to pass multiple certificates anyway? Looking at the [source](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-google/blob/master/google/resource_compute_target_https_proxy.go) and schema it doesn't have a `ValidateFunc` setting a max length so it doesn't look like Terraform enforces this at plan or apply time. If Google accepts it then it should be fine. If that's the case it might be worth raising a pull request to fix the docs here.

Comment: I trusted the doc and I was wrong.
It's working perfectly I will make a PR to update the doc.
Thank :)

Answer (score 1):

The [Terraform documentation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/r/compute_target_https_proxy.html#ssl_certificates) was wrong and it does allow multiple `ssl_certificates` to be passed.

I've raised a [pull request to fix the documentation](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-google/pull/4316).